# Error al mostrar datos de un arreglo en Handlebars

Tags: nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Buen día estoy intentando mostrar los datos de un array con el motor de plantillas handeblars en node.js

```
{{#each puestos}}
   <p>{{this}}</p>
   <p>{{titulo}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Al imprimir "this" todo esta correcto, me muestra el siguiente arreglo:

> { salario: '1500', skills: [ 'Apollo', 'ReactJS', 'GraphQL' ], _id:
>   5e8ec91a36dcd404140f0667, titulo: 'React', empresa: 'React',
>   ubicacion: 'React', descripcion: 'React', candidatos: [],
>   url: 'react-pldrflpp8', __v: 0 }

Pero al intentar acceder a la propiedad "titulo" no me los muestra en la vista y manda el siguiente error a consola:

> Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "titulo"
>   because it is not an "own property" of its parent. You can add a
>   runtime option to disable the check or this warning: See
>   https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access
>   for details

Comment: Prueba con [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690923/handlebars-access-has-been-denied-to-resolve-the-property-from-because-it-is) solución

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me sigue mostrando el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto sería esto

```
{{#each puestos}}
   <p>{{puestos.salario}}</p>
   <p>{{puestos.titulo}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Nose si funciona con this, pero no lo probe.

Answer (score 0):

llegué tarde pero tal vez a alguien le sirva. Me pasaba lo mismo utilizando Node, mongoose y handlebars. Lo resolví agregando un lean al final de la busqueda.
Ejemplo: const cart = await CartsModel.findOne({ _id: id }).lean()

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/406543)